# Empty constructor in inheriting class C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have written a simple generic class in C#.

```
class Foo<T>
{
   public object O{get;set;}
   public Foo(object o)
   {
      O=o;
   }
}
```

and another class inheriting from it

```
class Bar:Foo<object>
{
   public Foo(object o):base(o)
   { }
}
```

My question is whether I can avoid writing that constructor in `Bar` class, because it does nothing special at all. PS: the parameter in constructor is necessary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you can't. There's no inheritance of constructors. The constructor in `Bar` *does* do something: it provides an argument to the base constructor, using its own parameter for that argument. There's no way of doing that automatically.

The *only* constructor the compiler will supply for you automatically is one of equivalent to:

```
public Bar() : base()
{
}
```

for a concrete class, or for an abstract class:

```
protected Bar() : base()
{
}
```

... and that's only provided if you don't supply any other constructors explicitly.

Comment: and it also tells the compiler "do not generate default constructor for this class"

Comment: @dotctor: Hopefully that's now covered by my final sentence :)